# In .NET MAUI when selected an item on Flyout menu, the page does not change

Tags: c#, .net, maui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="ArnoFormulynas.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ArnoFormulynas"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False">

    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Title="Termodynamics"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:FormulaPage}"
                      Route="FormulaPage">
            
        </ShellContent>

        <ShellContent Title="Molecular Physics"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:FormulaPage}"
                      Route="FormulaPage">

        </ShellContent>

    </FlyoutItem>

</Shell>
```

Everything worked until it didn't :D, basically when I click on a FlyoutItem, the Title just doesn't change and it doesn't load anything new. AppShell.xaml.cs wasn't really changed so I'm just a little lost. (Formula Page is just a blank ContentPage)

I tried separating each shell content into different flyout items and just messed around in the code, couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Everything worked until it didn't :D, basically when I click on a FlyoutItem, the Title just doesn't change and it doesn't load anything new. AppShell.xaml.cs wasn't really changed so I'm just a little lost. (Formula Page is just a blank ContentPage)

The reason the title didn't change is that the routes for both ShellContents are the same. You can change the `Route` to this:

```xml
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Title="Termodynamics"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:FormulaPage}"
                      Route="FormulaPage1">
        </ShellContent>

        <ShellContent Title="Molecular Physics"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:FormulaPage}"
                      Route="FormulaPage2">
        </ShellContent>

    </FlyoutItem>
```

The Title will change according to the FlyoutItem you clicked.